# How do you change the Store Icon for a Chrome Extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

How do you change the Store Icon for a Chrome Extension in the Chrome Web Store?

The field I'm looking to change is found under 'Chrome Web Store Developer Dashboard' -> 'Store Listing' -> 'Graphic Assets'. When I first created the extension, I could upload an image there. In fact, I had to in order to submit the extension. But after that initial upload I have not found any way to change it, either in the manifest or through the dashboard.

Is it really set forever? Is there no way to change it?

BTW, the icons section of manifest.json lists the following icons, but with a different graphical asset than the initial upload. And the default action icon is correct. It is just the web store listing I can't seem to change.

```json
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon-128.png",
    "64": "icon-64.png",
    "48": "icon-48.png",
    "32": "icon-32.png",
    "16": "icon-16.png"
  },
```

[image: Screen grab of the store icon field I want to change]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just stumbled upon this, as well.
Hover on the icon in the dev dashboard, there will be a trashcan that appears on the top right that you can click to delete the image.

Comment: Oh my god! That is some pretty poor UI design right there! Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Parakoos I am not able to find where to hover to change the icon. Any screenshot to help ? I have tried everything but couldn't find anything

Comment: @Niharika , I added a screenshot below.

Comment: Additionally, if you want to change the promotional image (which may be the image that shows up in the Store for your extension), you have to do the same for the "Small promo tile" or the "Marquee promo tile" which images described here: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/images/#promo

Answer (score 2):

This is in reply to @Niharika who asked for a screenshot.

[image]